# <a> Tag not clickable when it is inside a <label> Tag (Mobile devices)

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble in getting the `<a>`-tag to work inside a `<label>`-tag on Tablets and Mobile Devices.

What i want is that the `<label>` should be clickable to check the checkbox, and the `<a>` should be clickable to open up a Lightbox.

The Problem:

If I use the code down below the `<a>` is nested in the `<label>`, so the `<a>` is not clickable on Mobile Devices and the Lightbox doesn't trigger. The Code Below works on Desktop whatsover.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="foo" name="bar" value="1">
<label for="bar">You can <a href="#" data-type="inline" id="lightbox" >Click to open Lightbox</a></label>
```

And if I use this code Snippet the Lightbox Triggers on Click/Touch but the label Text isn't clickable on Mobile Devices to check the Checkbox.

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" value="1">
<label for="foo">Click me <a href="#" data-type="inline" id="lightbox"> to open a Lightbox</a></label>
```

Comment: This is by design. As you've placed a `for` attribute on the `label` it is also clickable, hence the browser is not 100% sure which element you're actually trying to click. It's the same reason why you cannot have nested `<a>` elements. You could try using `stopPropagation()` on the event, but this would be a crutch supporting the improper HTML.

Comment: You can't nest clickable elements inside one another.

Comment: @Terry yes, HTML5 allows this. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element: _“Content model: Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.”_ `a` is not one of those labelable elements, so this is valid HTML.

Comment: @Terry CBroe is right the authors code is valid. Try it on your own: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: My code does work on Desktop Browser, but it doesn't work on IPad/Phone and Android phone, like the way i want it to work ( 2nd Code Snippet )

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Works for me on iPad. Please clarify what you want to achieve...

Comment: While its not quite clear what your actual issue may be I tried to cover some use case scenarios. Please leave a comment if this is a step into your right direction of if not then why not (means clearify your issue...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tested on iPad and Desktop*

Please note that these are very raw sketches. When its more clear which approach is in the right direction I will provide a more generic, clean solution...

The most notable change I made is to change the markup slightly (so to say "de-nested" the `<a>`) which make it all a bit more simple.
In addition I added some functionalities between `<label>` and `<a>` which is maybe someting the author wants (but just a guess).

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  if (this.className == 'add-1') {
    $(this).prev().click();
  } else if (this.className == 'add-2') {
    alert('Hello');
  }
  alert('Hello');
});

$('label').click(function() {
  if (this.className == 'add-2') {
    $(this).next().click();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="foo" value="1">
<label for="foo">Click me to toggle checkbox </label>
<a href="#" data-type="inline" id="lightbox">Click me to open a Lightbox</a>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="foo1" value="1">
<label for="foo1">Click me to toggle checkbox </label>
<a href="#" data-type="inline" id="lightbox" class="add-1"> Click me to toggle checkbox AND open a Lightbox</a>

<hr>

<input type="checkbox" id="foo2" value="1">
<label for="foo2" class="add-2">Click me to toggle checkbox  AND open a Lightbox</label>
<a href="#" data-type="inline" id="lightbox"> Click me to open a Lightbox</a>
```

## UPDATE 1

```js
$('.listen').click(function( event ) {
  if ('A' === event.target.nodeName) {
    alert('Hello Lightbox');
    return false; // stop bubbling
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="listen">
  <input type="checkbox" id="bar" name="bar" value="1">
  <label for="bar">Click me <a href="#" data-type="inline" class="lightbox">Click me to open a Lightbox</a> to toggle checkbox </label>
</div>
```

## UPDATE 2

```js
$('a').click(function( event ) {
  alert('Hello Lightbox');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="bar" name="bar" value="1">
<label for="bar">Click me <a href="#" data-type="inline" class="lightbox">Click me to open a Lightbox</a> to toggle checkbox</label>
```

Comment: the second one is the checkbox i want to create. Right now im still testing some other options

Comment: So the second one does it for you??? If yes I will update to a cleaner version...

Comment: well in my code it is ordered like this. <label> Lorem <a> Click </a> Ipsum </label>. I just took your Markup. <label></label> <a></a> and this works for me, i just need to style it with css so the label and a tag line up

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. **What are your prerequisites?** Just clearify what you are after. EG you want to toggle checkbox when clicking the link? Or you must use a specific markup (order, etc.)?

Comment: I want to toggle the checkbox when i click the checkbox or the label text and it should NOT check the checkbox if i press the link, it should open the lightbox if i click the link

Comment: @GreennT so version 1 is what you are after - isn't it? If not please clearify why not - it behaves like you described: label and labelText toggles checkbox | link opens lightbox. Do you have trouble with the CSS?

Comment: Yes Version 1 is what i need to do. If i use the Markup from Version 1 everything works fine. Yes i have trouble with the CSS, it doesnt behave like i want it to be, i will try my best to solve it by myself for now if i am not succesfull with it i will comment here

Comment: @GreennT in the snippets in your question there is no text after `</a>`. Please update your questions markup to your actual needs. I'm sure I can update accordingly afterwards... This is the reason why its so important to post use case markup (minified & abstracted but still real life)

Comment: @GreennT the text after the `<a/>`: do you want it to have any functionality? like toggling the checkbox?

Comment: Hey @GreennT please see my "update 1" at the bottom of my answer. I switched back to your original order (the nested `<label><a></a></label>` version) but made the event listening and event callback a bit more error prone. Works like a charme on my iPad and Desktop... "update 2" is about the version which you already preferred but added text after `</a>` which also toggles the checkbox. Hope it helps - if not leave a comment or ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

***Try with these***

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
```

or

```
$(document).on('click touch', function () {
```